# Color change on hover over image and link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

My site setup is roughly like this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="image1.html">Image title 1</a></li>
<li><a href="image2.html">Image title 2</a></li>
<li><a href="image3.html">Image title 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
<a href="image1.html"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="image2.html"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>
<a href="image3.html"><img src="image3.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

What I need is a way to change color of both image title and image border of the coresponding image on hover over either title or image. So if you hover over the link in the menu for image1 both title and image are affected and the same if you would hover over the image.
I got the change color on hover done with css - no problem there.
But no matter what I try I can get both title and image to change at the same time. How do I link them together so they will know they both have to change color?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Withoud classes sounds a bit weard: **https://fiddle.jshell.net/g0wsywaj/**

```
$(function(){
  $('.menu a, .content a').hover(
    function(){
      $('a[href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'"]').addClass("hover");
    },
    function(){
      $('a[href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'"]').removeClass("hover")
  })
})
```

Comment: Even with the '.menu a, .content a' part of the code, all my links everywhere got this "feature" applied, which isn't ok. Am I doing something wrong here??

Comment: EDIT: nevermind, it's working perfectly if you don't forget .menu and .content before a in css file...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to bind together all anchor tags (`a`), so when you hover, all the others anchors with the same `href` will be given the same class (`hover`).

```
$("a").mouseenter(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  $('a[href="' + href + '"]').addClass('hover');
}).mouseleave(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  $('a[href="' + href + '"]').removeClass('hover');
});
```

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctympw0m/)